# Inconsistent UV-surface sizes on different models

Tags: texturing, uv, three.js, pbr

My workflow starts in Blender (v2.93.0, OsX), where models are exported to GLB/GLTF and then imported in a web application running ThreeJS.

I have a bunch of products, all similar in size. Some have more extra details than others, creating larger UV-maps.

The problem is that the level of complexity in the products creates UV-maps where the similar parts get different amount of space in the UV-map. The result of this is differences in the textures.

I unwrap using *Smart UV-project*.

Is there any way of controlling a specific face/surface's percental coverage of the total UV-map? That way I can make sure all products have the same look, no matter of their complexity level?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "complexity level". Using smart uv project is a bad idea in general because you're wasting a lot of UV space, I'd suggest unwrap the objects properly. Anyway, I guess your actual issue is a non equal texel density right? There is an add-on which might help: https://github.com/mrven/Blender-Texel-Density-Checker

Comment: @brockmann Complexity-level is the amount of faces. Some products have extra details that takes up more space than others in a UV-map. Causing the common areas to vary in size.

I also bake AO-maps with a margin of 1px, that's why I use Smart UV Project which let's me add margin for all UV-islands.

Will take a look at the plugin. Thank you!